# Autocomplete jQuery remote XML file

Tags: php, jquery, xml

I have the following code configured to reference an offsite XML file and autocomplete and return the value.  It is not working no matter if I hardcode the data element like you see below or if I comment the data: element out. I've tried to change the Type: from Post to Get in both scenarios as well.  I've also confirmed that the .xml is in the URL path specified as well as try to simply place it in the same directory as the .php file you see below.  No errors are generated on the webserver either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

  <title></title>

  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.3.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/start/jquery-ui.css">

  <style type='text/css'>
    .red {color: red}
  </style>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

$(window).load(function(){
$.ajax({
    url: "domain/file.xml", 
    type: "POST", 
    dataType: "xml", 
    data: {
        xml: "<geonames><geoname><name>London</name><geonameId>2643743</geonameId><countryCode>GB</countryCode><countryName>United Kingdom</countryName></geoname><geoname><name>London</name><geonameId>6058560</geonameId><countryCode>CA</countryCode><countryName>Canada</countryName></geoname><geoname><name>The Tower of London</name><geonameId>6286786</geonameId><countryCode>GB</countryCode><countryName>United Kingdom</countryName></geoname></geonames>"
    }, //should not need to define 'data' on your own xml call
    success: function(xmlResponse) {
        var data = $("geoname", xmlResponse).map(function() {
            return {
                value: $("name", this).text() + ", " + ($.trim($("countryName", this).text()) || "(unknown country)"),
                id: $("geonameId", this).text()
            };
        }).get();
        $("#test").autocomplete({
            source: function(req, response) {
                var re = $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(req.term);
                var matcher = new RegExp("^" + re, "i");
                response($.grep(data, function(item) {
                    return matcher.test(item.value);
                }));
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("p#result").html(ui.item ? "Selected: " + ui.item.value + ", geonameId: " + ui.item.id : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
            }
        });
    }
});
});//]]> 

</script>

</head>
<body>
<p  class="ui-widget">Try typing 'Lo' it will match on 'London'.</p>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="test">London matches: </label>
    <input id="test" />
</div>

<p id="result" class="ui-widget red"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can open the remote URL directly in the browser or a browser addon, but not using Ajax, the same-origin policy and missing CORS headers are the most likely reason.

The remote resource has to provide [CORS headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). Otherwise the browser will not open it in the XHR object (jQuery.ajax() uses XHR internally).

Open the network tab of the developer tools in your browser an check the request/response headers.

Comment: what about if I place the xml in the same directory as the .php and not reference it as a http: and just    url: "file.xml", ...that does not work either though?

Comment: The directory is not relevant (that is server side). The Ajax request has to go to the same domain. (A relative URL uses the same domain). If the domain is different you need CORS headers. You need to debug the request/response with the developer tools of the browser.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!  I did some reading on the headers as you specified and it makes sense now.  Your links led me here which I ended up using.  Thanks again!  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Server-Side_Access_Control